# How to get height of 2D gamobject with sprite renderer component in unity3d 4.5?

Tags: unity-game-engine, height, size, 2d, sprite

I have a 2D gameobject and I want to find out what the height of my gameobject is in each screen size.

I am getting the height of my game character by calculating the distance between two empty gameobjects but i figure out this is wrong !

Is there a better way?

Comment: Use the variables contained within `GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().bounds`: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-bounds.html

Comment: i don't understand exactly what are they but for all screen sizes, min and max are same and i've been using renderer.bounds.size.y but it's same either

Comment: Variables within Bounds will be the same for any screen size, yep, so then use Camera.WorldToScreenPoint to convert what you need to them to screen coords: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToScreenPoint.html

Comment: Thanks a lot !
may I ask another question ? 
What exactly Camera.renderer.bounds.size.y return ? (I know it is height of my object) I mean it is pixel or something else ?
Because I think it is too much for being size of object in screen !
and if my English is bad sorry about this !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default size (in px) for sprites of a unit in Unity is 100. If you select your sprite you can find the field "Pixels To Units" in the Inspector.

Let's say your object is at normal size, so x and y equal 1.0 . Usually you will give your object a 2d collider; Box 2D collider for this example. You will notice that the collider's default size won't equal 1.0 . Its bounds are based on the Pixels To Units value I mentioned before. In this example, let us have a sprite with the dimension of 128 x 128. The bounds of your collider would now equal 1.28, because 100px equal 1.0 unit (128 / 100 = 1.28).

Now we can calculate the on screen size in px very easily by dividing the width of our object by its collider's bounds: 1.0 / 1.28 = 0.78125
Now, just multiply by our Pixels To Units value (100): 0.78125 * 100 = 78.125px

Codewise it could look like this:

```
void OnMouseOver() {
    Vector2 objDimensionInPX = GetDimensionInPX(GameObject.FindWithTag("Player"));

    Debug.Log ("Sprite / GameObject size in pixels is (Width x Height): " + objDimensionInPX.x + " x " + objDimensionInPX.y);

}

private Vector2 GetDimensionInPX(GameObject obj) {
    Vector2 tmpDimension;

    tmpDimension.x = obj.transform.localScale.x / obj.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite.bounds.size.x;  // this is gonna be our width
    tmpDimension.y = obj.transform.localScale.y / obj.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite.bounds.size.y;  // this is gonna be our height

    return tmpDimension;
}
```

Comment: it should actually be  multiplying instead of dividing
tmpDimension.x = obj.transform.localScale.x * obj.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite.bounds.size.x;  // this is gonna be our width

Comment: In my case this returns a bounds with no x and y properties, and all other values set to 0.

Comment: If the object is rotated, these will return incorrect values.